# Expand Image by clicking on it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject with Image type. It is set to certain size and I want to make users able to click on it, thus expanding it to its original size in a new window. For example, gameobject with Image property is set to center. When user clicks on image, it creates or activates existing gameobject but in an expanded view (original size). How would I go about that? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Separate this task into two steps: 1.Detect click on the Image. 2.Resize or scale the image. Not sure where you are stuck but each of these two should be easy to do if you search them.

Comment: @Programmer I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem and if you run into issues, edit you question and add that code to it then explain what the issue is. I am sure many here are will help you.

Comment: Sounds good! @Programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about executing this code in OnClick event handler?

```
gameObject.Scale = Vector3.one * 2; // This scales two times
```